# equivalent java function of TextEncoder().encode

Tags: javascript, java, utf-8

What is the equivalent java function of encoder.encode . I want to convert following JavaScript funtion to java .

```
function fun(){
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
const view = encoder.encode('xxx').buffer
console.log(view); 

}
```

but the thing is couldn't find any equivalent code to get similar result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;



byte[] view = "xxx".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```